# Coding a sum and product together in R

Tags: r, kernel, kernel-density

I am new to R and I am trying to get some experience coding. I have quite a large program but I can't seem to figure out how to code the following. Any help would be greatly appreciated

`X`: a data matrix with "r"-many columns and "n"-many rows (r x n)

`x`: a vector with "r" many variables

`l`: a vector with "r" many variables

`z_j`: all the values of in the column "j" of the data matrix `X`

[image: This is what I am trying to code]

This is what I have so far, but it's not giving me the expected output

```
X<-matrix(c(0,1,2,1,2,4), ncol = 2)
x<-numeric()
x[1] <- 2
x[2] <- 5
l<-numeric()
l[1] <- 0.5
l[2] <- 0.5
   for (j in 1:ncol(X)){
    for (i in 1:nrow(X)){
      mean(prod((l[j]^(abs(X[i,j]-x[j])))/sum(l[j]^(abs(X[i,j]-X[1:nrow(X),j])))))
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of input? Say, a 2x3 matrix `X`, as well as corresponding test values for `x`,  and `l`, and the desired output for that input?

Comment: At a glance, it looks like all your operation are vectorized, so it may be possible that you don't need `for` loops at all--maybe using some nice matrix operations instead. If you do need `for` loops, then having `mean` and `prod` **inside** the loops is a problem. You would want to have a loop have compute values and put them in a vector, and then `prod()` that vector, and then `mean()` that product for each row.

Comment: I have included some code above for the sample I computed by hand. I tested with the same l-values for the vector l, but it will vary in practice. The expected output by hand would be approximately 0.0803. I will also give your second comment a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never aggregating up the product and sum; but your formula looks right enough.

If you follow your notation a bit more closely and break it up; I think it is easier to follow.

```
# Create toy data
n <- 10
r <- 5
X <- matrix(runif(r*n), n, r)

x <- runif(r)
l <- runif(r)

# Making the sum
summand <- 0
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  product <- 1
  for (j in seq_len(r)) {
     top <- l[j]^abs(X[i, j] - x[j])
     bot <- sum(l[j]^abs(X[i, j] - X[, j]))
     product <- product*top/bot
  }
  summand <- summand + product/n
}

print(summand)
# [1] 4.709275e-05
```

This can probably be made much more efficient using proper vectorization. Anyway, on you data, I get:

```
print(summand)
#[1] 0.07704795
```

Comment: this is much clearer to visual, thank you very much